# s3 Policy has invalid action - s3:ListAllMyBuckets

Tags: amazon-s3, policy, bucket

I'm trying these [policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615168/s3-policy-limiting-access-to-only-one-bucket-listing-included) through [console.aws.amazon.com](https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3) on my buckets:

```
    {
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
          ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::itnighq",
          "Condition": {}
        },
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:PutObjectAclVersion"
          ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::itnighq/*",
          "Condition": {}
        },
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
          "Resource": "*",
          "Condition": {}
        }
      ]
    }
```

But I'm getting this error message:

**Policy has invalid action - s3:ListAllMyBuckets**

It doesn't seem to like **"Resource": "*"** , I've also tried to use **arn:aws:s3:::****, but it doesn't work either.

Anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured out myself. It needs to be done in the [IAM](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam), not in S3 itself...

Comment: Could you please describe the steps for how to apply this policy in IAM?

Answer (score 19):

As zdev mentioned, you need to do this for the IAM. Go to the [IAM console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#home) and navigate to *Users > Permissions > Inline policies > Create > Custom*, and enter this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This policy contains the following error: The following Statement Ids are invalid: "Allow user to list all S3 buckets"

Comment: @zPrima thanks, looks like [the `Sid` field is optional](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_grammar.html#policies-grammar-bnf) anyway. I've removed it.

Answer (score 2):

@dnlbrky You need to do this by setting the policy on for the IAM user/group/role and set it by either using the AWS console for the IAM user/group or by calling put_[role/user/group]_policy boto API call.

Answer (score 1):

**Anyone getting same issue**:

S3 bucket `Policy Actions` are different from `IAM policy actions`.
Can reference to s3 actions from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html.

Or try with the following actions

```
"Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
```