# S3 Bucket Creation: Restrict to Specific Name Pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Is there a way to specify a bucket creation policy so that the a user with the assigned role can only create buckets with a specified name pattern such as `company-dbbackup-*` and no other name patterns?

For example, the user would be allowed to create bucket with names `company-dbbackup-March2017` and `company-dbbackup-fullarchive` but not `test-bucketname-invalid`.

What I have right now:

```
{
    "Sid": "Stmt1493212897117",
    "Action": [
        "s3:CreateBucket",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
}
```

But this allows me to create buckets with any name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out to be relatively simple (unless I've overlooked something). I simply have split the permissions as follows:

```
{
    "Sid": "RestrictCreationToNamePolicy",
    "Action": [
        "s3:CreateBucket"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::company-dbbackup-*"
}

{
    "Sid": "AllowListingOfBuckets",
    "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
}
```

I haven't found a way to restrict listing only buckets with the naming policy. If I restrict the second statement to the resource `arn:aws:s3:::company-dbbackup-*`, I get an Access Denied when trying to list buckets.

EDIT: Apparently restricting the listing is not possible, [here's a good Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615168/is-there-an-s3-policy-for-limiting-access-to-only-see-access-one-bucket/18089783#18089783) with possible workarounds. Here's [also another good discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736048/restrict-list-of-buckets-for-a-specific-user).

Comment: Do you know if this is still true?  I have not been able to restrict the create bucket options but I have been able to restrict the put and list buckets by wildcard as you show above.

Comment: Sorry I don't know if this still works as expected. Not currently touching AWS much these days.